# Remove 4 sub directories using htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have to remove 4 sub directories from url using .htaccess

Url is http://website.com/wp-content/themes/site/what-is-kinesiology/index.php

I need this as http://website.com/what-is-kinesiology/

I have around 10000 pages in website.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule /(.+) /wp-content/themes/site/$1/index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Is the rewirte engine turned on? - try adding RewriteEngine On at the top of the .htaccess file.